# What is the best way to create an array of the "values" in non-contiguous ranges in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have looked into the vba Union method but the example only shows how to apply a formula to these ranges.  Every time I try to copy these ranges into an array I end up with only some of the columns.  I am doing this:

```
Dim aRng As Range: Set aRng = wbkFirstfile.Sheets(1).Range("H2:H" + CStr(lastRow))
Dim bRng As Range: Set bRng = wbkFirstfile.Sheets(1).Range("P2:P" + CStr(lastRow))
Dim cRng As Range: Set cRng = wbkFirstfile.Sheets(1).Range("Q2:Q" + CStr(lastRow))
Dim dRng As Range: Set dRng = wbkFirstfile.Sheets(1).Range("U2:U" + CStr(lastRow))
Dim eRng As Range: Set eRng = wbkFirstfile.Sheets(1).Range("V2:V" + CStr(lastRow))
Dim fRng As Range: Set fRng = wbkFirstfile.Sheets(1).Range("W2:W" + CStr(lastRow))
Dim uRng As Range: Set uRng = Union(aRng, bRng, cRng)
Dim uRng2 As Range: Set uRng2 = Union(dRng, fRng)
```

This only works for 3 of the 6 columns even when I try to access it directly e.g. area(3).cells(r,c) etc... I get an application defined error.

**UPDATE**
I also updated uRng to:

```
Dim uRng As Range: Set uRng = Union(aRng, bRng, cRng, dRng, eRng, fRng)
```

I try to access it as:

```
MsgBox uRng2.Areas(1).Cells(2, 1)
```

or

```
MsgBox uRng2.Areas(2).Cells(2, 1)
```

or

```
MsgBox uRng2.Areas(3).Cells(2, 1)
```

and it works fine.... anything after area 3 (which I figured there were 6 areas) causes the application defined error.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I also updated uRng to:
    `Dim uRng As Range: Set uRng = Union(aRng, bRng, cRng, dRng, eRng, fRng)`

I try to access it as:
     `MsgBox uRng2.Areas(1).Cells(2, 1)`
or
`MsgBox uRng2.Areas(2).Cells(2, 1)`
or
`MsgBox uRng2.Areas(3).Cells(2, 1)`

and it works fine.... anything after area 3 (which I figured there were 6 areas) causes the application defined error.

Comment: Do you just want an array of the values from those columns? If so, you don't want `Union`, you want `Index`.

Comment: Yes, @Rory, I am looking for an array with those values so that I can loop through it update a few of the values, add a column and then copy that array to a new sheet...  What would it look like using index?  I do not want to loop through the entire range and apply each cell to the array unless I truly have to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you only want an array of the values, you can use `Index` with a couple of array arguments:

```
Dim v
With wbkFirstfile.Sheets(1).Range("H2:W" & lastRow)
v = Application.Index(.Value2, .Worksheet.Evaluate("ROW(" & .Columns(1).Address & ")-1"), Array(1, 9, 10, 15, 16))
End With
```

The `Evaluate` part creates an array of 'row' indices (from 1 to n) and the last array is the indices of the columns you want (relative to the range, so H is column 1).

Comment: So would I have an array for each of the ranges at the end of the function?  If so how can I make them one array?

Comment: No - that produces **one** array (`v`) with the values you want. I was explaining how it is constructed.

Comment: I ran it and noticed that... sorry for the extraneous question!  I suspect your solution is the correct one I am just confused as to how to get it to capture all the data.  I only get three of the column headers and then none of the data the array is empty after that... Here is the result:




[Result Array](http://imgur.com/12wYeNn)


There is definitely data in those columns.

Comment: Did you qualify the range with the correct book/sheet in your actual code? (I just edited the answer to include that)

Comment: Thanks so much you are a lifesaver... I have marked this as the answer.